# jquery (js) string replace problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to highlight all digits in string, i try to cover matched digits with  tag but cann't! Here is my code

```
regexp = /[1-9]/g;
//$("#task").val() it's my input
title = $("#task").val().replace(regexp,'<span class="int">$1</span>');
```

**$1** - i found in google some samples, where $1 must be first matched value, but it's dosn't work!

Comment: Should work. What is the value returned by $("#task").val() ? What is the value of title after you run this code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var regexp = /(\d+)/g; // use \d to match all digits, + to capture one or more
var title = 'testing 123'.replace(regexp,'<span class="int">$1</span>');
```

Result: `testing <span class="int">123</span>`

Answer (score 4):

`$1` will replace the first *capture group* matched in the regex.

Your regex doesn't have any capture groups, so it doesn't do anything.

You need to wrap the regex in parenthesis to make it capture.

For example:

```
title = $("#task").val().replace(/([1-9])/,'<span class="int">$1</span>');
```

---

Note that this won't match `0`; you may have meant `[0-9]`.
Also note that this will surround every single digit with a `<span>` tag.  If you actually want to surround each number with a span tag (eg, `<span class="int">123</span>`), you'll need to add a `+` to tell it to match one or more digits, like this:

```
title = $("#task").val().replace(/([0-9]+)/,'<span class="int">$1</span>');
```

Comment: Also, you could use [0-9] to match all ten digits, and [0-9]+ or [1-9]+ to match groups of digits instead of individual digits.

Comment: And then also: `\d` is basically `[0-9]`